# Get Custom Option Values of a product magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-options, simple-product, attribute-options

I have two custom options for a product. Color and Size and both are drop-downs. In product detail pages, I have to display all available colors of that product.

I tried the following code and it works:

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $o) {
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
        print_r($value->getData());
    }
}
```

But it returns all the values of Color and Size. But I only need the color values. That is I want to select the custom options by color.

Comment: You can try by adding $value->getData('add column name which contains values.')

Comment: @Arjun  ` code`print_r($value->getData('color'));`code ` not working

Comment: My answer hasn't helped you?

Comment: Check the link, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-product-custom-options-value-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Comment: Any have idea I used Mageworx Product Options extension and need to get those custom option field in product rest API option's value ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $o) {
    if ($o->getTitle() != 'Color') { // or another title of option
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
        print_r($value->getData());
    }
}
```

You should search for your option by the title because the option ID is unknown.

Answer (score 3):

```
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

foreach($customOptions as $optionKey => $optionVal):
               foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
                      echo $valuesVal->getId().' '.$valuesVal->getTitle();
                }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Everything is good just if someone is reffering this please use Dependency Injection method instead of Object Manager

Answer (score -8):

This topic is old but I have found a solution. (For all people that found this topic via Google, like me :D)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $optionisset = false;
    $allItems = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    //loop all cart items and check options
    foreach($allItems as $item) {
        $itemOptions = $item->getOptions();
        $itemOptions = unserialize($itemOptions[0]['value']);
        //get set option ids for parent and child option
        foreach ($itemOptions['options'] as $key=>$value) {
            $parentOptionId = $key;
            $optionId = $value;
            $option = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->load($parentOptionId);
            $product_id = $option->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
            $options = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
            //loop all parent options
            foreach($options as $option) {
                $values = $option->getValues();
                //loop all child options
                foreach($values as $value) {
                    //if name is MyOptionName and it is set for this cart item
                    if($value->getTitle() == "MyOptionName" && $value->getOptionTypeId() == $optionId) {
                     //Do something here
                        $optionisset = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if($optionisset == true) break;
            }
            if($optionisset == true) break;
        }
        if($optionisset == true) break;
    }
```

You can change "MyOptionName" to your Option Name and you will get back true if one of your products in your cart is set to this option.

Comment: You should not use the object manager like this. You should be injecting your classes using Magento 2's dependency injection.

Comment: Using break is not a good idea...any other solution ?