# Get values of customizable option

Tags: magento2, product, option

Is there a way to get the SKU of the option of my product ?

Can't make anything works 
Tried this :

```
$customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

foreach($customOptions as $optionKey => $optionVal):
               foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
                      echo $valuesVal->getId().' '.$valuesVal->getTitle();
                }
endforeach;
```

but **$optionVal->getValues()** is

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

[image: of po]

Comment: please check https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-product-custom-options-value-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Custom Option Values of a product magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125646/get-custom-option-values-of-a-product-magento-2)

Comment: @RutveeSojitra the code is from there, but I get the error I've said, i'll try your link.

Comment: Ok your link work, I didn't get it was to get the value of the "dropdown", "multiselect" but not for the "text" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
$productId = $_product->getId();
$customOptions = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository')->get($productId);
$productOption = $product->getOptions();
foreach($productOption as $option)
{
    print_r($option->getData()); //get All Data Of Option

}
```

Comment: how can I get this from Quote. I need the once only selected in quote

Comment: you mean get option from quote ?

Comment: Yes i need customizable options from quote

Comment: For this task :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/309935/72911

Comment: I got the answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309831/need-to-get-customizable-option-title-values-from-array-in-quote.  But the link you shared can you guide me on that, It will be  a great help.

Comment: you can use before adatocart event for that ??