# Magento2 when same product in cart is added with different custom options update cart product

Tags: magento2, customizable-options

As per magento2 behaviour if I select same product second time with different custom options it add product second time.
[image]

I want that there should be only 1 product & product should be updated

1. Here first time I added product with test custom options to cart
2. Second time with teast2 custom options to cart

I want second time to be updated in cart not add product seperately

How can I achieve this?